Is σ-algebra firstorderizable?
The definition of a topological space is firstorderizable, as neatly explained by this answer. However, that problem enjoys the fact that topological spaces require closure under arbitrary unions and finite intersections, both easily expressed with first-order axioms and axiom-schemas, while $\sigma$-algebras require closure under countable unions and countable intersections (ignoring closure under complement). I've tried my best to find the answer online, but the Internet is unexpectedly silent about this question.
How can one express $\sigma$-algebras using a first-order theory? And if that is impossible, wouldn't that cause any problems with formalizing dependent theories, e.g., measure theory? ("Formalizing" is meant in the same sense that ZFC is declared as a formalization of mathematics due to its reliance on firstorderizability, in case you hopefully find this sentence philosophically valid.)

I don't understand your last sentence in parentheses. ZFC is a first-order theory, and of course you can express the theory of σ-algebras in ZFC (add to ZFC a constant $S$ and the axioms that make $S$ a σ-algebra). In that sense the definition is “firstorderizable”, but this notion is quite fuzzy as I understand it. I would be surprised if the class of σ-algebras was an elementary class.

@JeanAbouSamra I might need to clarify my question: as far as I know, we cannot express "being countable" in first-order logic. See my other question, for instance.

This depends on what exactly you want this formalization to achieve. For example, to go around the issue of impossibility of enforcing countability, you could just add a sort to the language to represent natural numbers, and declare that this sort satisfy Peano’s axioms. Then, as long as you have enough sorts to represent enough types, you can define countability using the sort representing natural numbers. It won’t match countability as defined in the metatheory, because Löwenheim-Skolem, but it should be sufficient for most practical purposes.

(And in any case, modern mathematics is usually formalized in ZFC, not as a collection of theories independent from ZFC. So there’s really no issue with “formalizing dependent theories” even if formalizing $\sigma$-algebra as its own theory is impossible.)

@DavidGao thanks! Could you kindly write this as an answer so I can accept it? It would also be neat to point out why a standalone $\sigma$-algebra theory is impossible (i.e., why we can't avoid additional structures, such as natural numbers, while enforcing countability in the Löwenheim-Skolem sense).
